# What is the purpose of using (n/8) and (n*7/8) in the lines of the C++ code below?

Tags: c++

I'm working on the C++ code of the A-star algorithm and the code in this link: 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577457-a-star-shortest-path-algorithm/

```
 // fillout the map matrix with a '+' pattern
    for(int x=n/8;x<n*7/8;x++)
    {
        map[x][m/2]=1;
    }
    for(int y=m/8;y<m*7/8;y++)
    {
        map[n/2][y]=1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just numerical values. If you think about that 2D `map` as of linear 2D space, `n/8` and `n*7/8` will give you 1/8th and 7/8th of he space, respectively. E.g. for a map sized 8x8, the result will look like this:

```
  01234567 n
0 ........
1 ....1... ---\ starts at m/8 
2 ....1...    |
3 ....1...    |
4 .111111.    | 
5 ....1...    |
6 ....1... ---/ ends at one less than m*7/8
7 ........

m     \-------- positioned at n/2
```

Since `n == m == 8`, `n/8 = 1`, and `n*7/8 == 7` (but the loop is specified to end 1 before 7).

Comment: Thank you so much dear sir for your answer; After your permission; what the purpose of this loop here?.

Comment: @HHadi to generate the shape of a `+` in the array, probably to make the A* have an actually challenging problem to solve.

Comment: I always see the plus shape of the obstacles, It means the shape of obstacles will be always as a plus right?.

Comment: Thanks indeed I got it, sir.

Comment: @Dear Sir Bartek. Could you clarify the lines 257 to 271 for me, please?.

Comment: @HHadi Sure, if you make another question

Comment: @Thank you in advance, but unfortunately, I have to wait one week until to post another question. As u know the policy of the website. :(

Comment: OK, see you in a week!

Comment: @OK Sir, Thank u so much... See u next Week.:)

Comment: @Dear Sir... Hello again. I'm lucky today. I post another question. Could you check it, please?.